# Javascript 'this' versus object name

Tags: javascript, object, this

A question spurred by curiosity, if I have the following code, what's the benefit (beyond just the simplicity) of calling a property via `this` instead of `user` in the `show_name` method?

```
var user = {

    name : 'John Doe',

    show_name : function(){

        alert(this.name);

        // OR

        alert(user.name);
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that there might be other side-effects using `this`: `user.show_name.call(null);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference becomes obvious, if you have a look at this example. It creates a second object and sets the prototype accordingly.

```
var user = {

    name : 'John Doe',

    show_name : function(){

        alert(this.name);

        // OR

        alert(user.name);
    }
};

user2 = Object.create( user );
user2.name = "someone else";

user2.show_name();
```

Here `this.name` refers to the current object's `name` property, whereas `user.name` always refers to the original `name` property.

Answer (score 9):

By using `this` you ensure that after changing your variable name e.g. from `user` to `something` your code still works.

Other than that, I imagine that (on some browsers) there may be some performance gain too, since with `user.name` browser has to lookup in context outside your function while using `this.name` sticks to current context.

---

**Sample Code**

```js
var user = {
    name : 'John Doe',
    show_name : function(){
        alert(user.name);
    }
};

var something = user; // Passing the object to another variable
user = null;          // Make the user variable point to something else

something.show_name();
```

If you run the code above, you'll hit an error at the following line:

```js
alert(user.name); // <-- user is null, so this will produce the following Error:
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Now, if we switch to `this` instead of `user`, our code will work:

```js
var user = {
    name : 'John Doe',
    show_name : function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
};

var something = user; // Passing the object to another variable
user = null;          // Make the user variable point to something else

something.show_name();
```

The above code will work since `this` will point to the object that executed the `show_name` function (this can be found in the left side of the . dot method notation and it's the object pointed to by `something`).

---

**REFERENCES:**

To learn more about how the execution context (in our example the object) affects the this binding, read [this excerpt](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#implicit-binding) from the wonderful book [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/README.md) by **Kyle Simpson**.

The following chapters thoroughly explain how `this` behaves in various contexts (but the whole series is worth reading!):

[Chapter 1: this Or That?](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)

[Chapter 2: this All Makes Sense Now!](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty straight-forward answer. Thanks.

Comment: How does referencing 'this' vs 'user' ensure that we can change 'name' to 'something'. Don't you mean that we can change 'user' to 'something'?

Comment: @Jacob - good catch - of course I meant to write `user` not `name`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same function in multiple places and have it be context sensitive.

```
function foo() {
  alert(this.name);
}

var a = { alert: foo, name: "A" };
var b = { alert: foo, name: "B" };
a.alert();
b.alert();
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use `this` or the function name depends on how the function will be called.

A function's `this` value is set by how the function is called or by *bind*, so if the function will always be called as a method of a suitable object, use `this`. But if it might be called any other way, or `this` should only reference a particular object, either use *bind* or the object name.

e.g. given the OP example, consider:

```
var x = user.showName;
x();
```

In the above, `showName` is called without setting its `this`, so it defaults to the global object and `this.name` within the function will likely no be what is expected.

Changing the function name is not a particularly onerous issue given the availability of reasonably powerful search and replace functionality in text editors.

Incidentally, this question is asked frequently. There is no "correct" answer, only advice on how to make choices in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making multiple copies of an object, you need `this` so you can reference the current obect. Using the name would reference the default object, not the copy you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

`this` here specifies that the object is part of the current name space and is accessible inside the object .. lets suppose your object name changes from `user` to `newUser` there will not be any dependency and remove any coupling issues..

Answer (score -1):

In case when jQuery is used `this` references to jQuery object. So, my choice is not to use `this` at all.

```
var user = {

name : 'John Doe',

alertName : function(){

    //  alert(this.name); //never

     alert(user.name);
  }
};
showName : function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
        //this here references jQuery object 
        $('#username').val(user.name);
    });

};
```

Also, object literal, generally, should not be used for creating multiple objects, so, using `this` inside object literal gives no benefits over using object variable name.

Comment: The question is asking what the benefit of using `this` instead of `user` is … it isn't looking for situations where the reverse is true.

Comment: @Quentin. You are right. But I found this question looking just from this point of view, and so may thousands of others.

Comment: You found the wrong question. The one you are looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: Now you aren't right. I have read the answers for this question and decided that benefits for using "this" are subtle and in my particular case I will be better without it.