# How to access the correct `this` inside a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I have a constructor function which registers an event handler:

```js
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data', function () {
        alert(this.data);
    });
}

// Mock transport object
var transport = {
    on: function(event, callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    }
};

// called as
var obj = new MyConstructor('foo', transport);
```

However, I'm not able to access the `data` property of the created object inside the callback. It looks like `this` does not refer to the object that was created, but to another one.

I also tried to use an object method instead of an anonymous function:

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data', this.alert);
}

MyConstructor.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this.name);
};
```

but it exhibits the same problems.

How can I access the correct object?

Comment: Related: [Preserving a reference to “this” in JavaScript prototype functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2025789/1048572)

Comment: Related: [“this” keyword in event methods when using JavaScript prototype object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1369004/1048572)

Comment: [Useful TypeScript page about this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript), mostly applicable to JS too.

Comment: @strattonn: Self-answering questions is an option in the UI and encouraged: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. I did this a couple of times for issues that came up over and over again to provide a canonical answer. The problem with canonical Q&A is that existing questions are often not phrased in a general enough way that focuses on the core problem.

Answer (score 2291, accepted):

### What you should know about `this`

`this` (aka "the context") is a special keyword inside each function and its value only depends on *how* the function was called, not how/when/where it was defined. It is not affected by lexical scopes like other variables (except for arrow functions, see below). Here are some examples:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

// normal function call
foo(); // `this` will refer to `window`

// as object method
var obj = {bar: foo};
obj.bar(); // `this` will refer to `obj`

// as constructor function
new foo(); // `this` will refer to an object that inherits from `foo.prototype`
```

To learn more about `this`, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

### How to refer to the correct `this`

#### Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

ECMAScript 6 introduced *arrow functions*, which can be thought of as lambda functions. They don't have their own `this` binding. Instead, `this` is looked up in scope just like a normal variable. That means you don't have to call `.bind`. That's not the only special behavior they have, please refer to the MDN documentation for more information.

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data', () => alert(this.data));
}
```

#### Don't use `this`

You actually don't want to access `this` in particular, but *the object it refers to*. That's why an easy solution is to simply create a new variable that also refers to that object. The variable can have any name, but common ones are `self` and `that`.

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    var self = this;
    transport.on('data', function() {
        alert(self.data);
    });
}
```

Since `self` is a normal variable, it obeys lexical scope rules and is accessible inside the callback. This also has the advantage that you can access the `this` value of the callback itself.

#### Explicitly set `this` of the callback - part 1

It might look like you have no control over the value of `this` because its value is set automatically, but that is actually not the case.

Every function has the method [`.bind` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which returns a new function with `this` bound to a value. The function has exactly the same behavior as the one you called `.bind` on, only that `this` was set by you. No matter how or when that function is called, `this` will always refer to the passed value.

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    var boundFunction = (function() { // parenthesis are not necessary
        alert(this.data);             // but might improve readability
    }).bind(this); // <- here we are calling `.bind()` 
    transport.on('data', boundFunction);
}
```

In this case, we are binding the callback's `this` to the value of `MyConstructor`'s `this`.

**Note:** When a binding context for jQuery, use [`jQuery.proxy` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead. The reason to do this is so that you don't need to store the reference to the function when unbinding an event callback. jQuery handles that internally.

#### Set `this` of the callback - part 2

Some functions/methods which accept callbacks also accept a value to which the callback's `this` should refer to. This is basically the same as binding it yourself, but the function/method does it for you. [`Array#map` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is such a method. Its signature is:

```
array.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

The first argument is the callback and the second argument is the value `this` should refer to. Here is a contrived example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = {multiplier: 42};

var new_arr = arr.map(function(v) {
    return v * this.multiplier;
}, obj); // <- here we are passing `obj` as second argument
```

**Note:** Whether or not you can pass a value for `this` is usually mentioned in the documentation of that function/method. For example, [jQuery's `$.ajax` method *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) describes an option called `context`:

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks.

---

### Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks/event handlers

Another common manifestation of this problem is when an object method is used as callback/event handler. Functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript and the term "method" is just a colloquial term for a function that is a value of an object property. But that function doesn't have a specific link to its "containing" object.

Consider the following example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.data = 42,
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
}

Foo.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log(this.data);
};
```

The function `this.method` is assigned as click event handler, but if the `document.body` is clicked, the value logged will be `undefined`, because inside the event handler, `this` refers to the `document.body`, not the instance of `Foo`.
As already mentioned at the beginning, what `this` refers to depends on how the function is **called**, not how it is **defined**.
If the code was like the following, it might be more obvious that the function doesn't have an implicit reference to the object:

```
function method() {
    console.log(this.data);
}


function Foo() {
    this.data = 42,
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
}

Foo.prototype.method = method;
```

**The solution** is the same as mentioned above: If available, use `.bind` to explicitly bind `this` to a specific value

```
document.body.onclick = this.method.bind(this);
```

or explicitly call the function as a "method" of the object, by using an anonymous function as callback / event handler and assign the object (`this`) to another variable:

```
var self = this;
document.body.onclick = function() {
    self.method();
};
```

or use an arrow function:

```
document.body.onclick = () => this.method();
```

Comment: Felix, I've read to this answer before but never replied.  I grow concerned that people use `self` and `that` to refer to `this`.  I feel this way because `this` is an overloaded variable used in different contexts; whereas `self` usually corresponds to the local instance and `that` usually refers to another object.  I know you did not set this rule, as I've seen it appear in a number of other places, but it is also why I've started to use `_this`, but am not sure how others feel, except for the non-uniform practice that has resulted.

Comment: @FelixKling, it allows you to be super lazy with code like `$(...).on('click', $.proxy(obj, 'function'))` and `$(...).off('click', obj.function)`.

Comment: @FelixKling It can be useful at times to rely on `Function.prototype.call ()` and `Function.prototype.apply ()`.  Particularly with `apply ()` I've gotten a lot of mileage.  I am less inclined to use `bind ()` perhaps only out of habit though I am aware ( but not certain ) that there may be slight overhead advantages to using bind over the other options.

Comment: It's important to note that `bind()` will take a **snapshot** of the context where it's first encountered during interpretation... That is to say, when JavaScript gets to the `bind()` function **for the first time**, it will take the context for `this` at that point! This can become tricky to troubleshoot, as the standard implementation of `bind()` CANNOT be altered. Once a function has been bound to another object, it will remain bound to that object, and attempting to rebind it won't work.

Answer (score 273):

### Here are several ways to access the parent context inside a child context -

1. You can use the `bind()` function.
2. Store a reference to context/this inside another variable (see the below example).
3. Use ES6 [Arrow](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/) functions.
4. Alter the code, function design, and architecture - for this you should have command over [design patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) in JavaScript.

## 1. Use the `bind()` function

```js
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data', ( function () {
        alert(this.data);
    }).bind(this) );
}
// Mock transport object
var transport = {
    on: function(event, callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    }
};
// called as
var obj = new MyConstructor('foo', transport);
```

If you are using Underscore.js - http://underscorejs.org/#bind

```
transport.on('data', _.bind(function () {
    alert(this.data);
}, this));
```

## 2. Store a reference to context/this inside another variable

```js
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
  var self = this;
  this.data = data;
  transport.on('data', function() {
    alert(self.data);
  });
}
```

## 3. Arrow function

```js
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
  this.data = data;
  transport.on('data', () => {
    alert(this.data);
  });
}
```

Comment: The bind() option is amazing its just passing the pointer of this Object to be the this on the other object (: Thanks !

Comment: "*…parent context inside child context*" is a misleading phrase as *this* is not part of a parent/child relationship. It often refers to the object a method was called on, but can be **any** object, or **any** value in strict mode. "[Context](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-executable-code-and-execution-contexts)" refers to an execution context (of which *this* is one parameter of many) which can't be referenced because ECMA-262 forbids it.

Answer (score 74):

It's all in the "magic" syntax of calling a method:

```
object.property();
```

When you get the property from the object and call it in one go, the object will be the context for the method. If you call the same method, but in separate steps, the context is the global scope (window) instead:

```
var f = object.property;
f();
```

When you get the reference of a method, it's no longer attached to the object. It's just a reference to a plain function. The same happens when you get the reference to use as a callback:

```
this.saveNextLevelData(this.setAll);
```

That's where you would bind the context to the function:

```
this.saveNextLevelData(this.setAll.bind(this));
```

If you are using jQuery you should use the `$.proxy` method instead, as `bind` is not supported in all browsers:

```
this.saveNextLevelData($.proxy(this.setAll, this));
```

Answer (score 59):

**You** ***should*** **know about "this" Keyword.**

**As per my view you can implement "this" in three ways**
***(Self|Arrow function|Bind Method)***

A function's `this` keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages.

It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode.

In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called.

It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

ES5 introduced the bind() method to set the value of a function's `this` regardless of how it's called,

And ES2015 introduced arrow functions that don't provide their own `this` binding (it retains this value of the enclosing lexical context).

**Method1:** Self - Self is being used to maintain a reference to the original this even as the context is changing. It's a technique often used in event handlers (especially in closures).

**Reference**: *[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)*

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    var self = this;
    transport.on('data', function () {
        alert(self.data);
    });
}
```

**Method2**: Arrow function - An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

Arrow function expressions are ill-suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.

**Reference**: *[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)*

```
  function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data',()=> {
        alert(this.data);
    });
}
```

**Method 3**: Bind - The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**Reference:** *[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)*

```
  function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data',(function() {
        alert(this.data);
    }).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 38):

#### The trouble with "context"

The term "context" is sometimes used to refer to the object referenced by *this*. Its use is inappropriate, because it doesn't fit either semantically or technically with [ECMAScript's *this*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3).

["Context"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/context) means the circumstances surrounding something that adds meaning, or some preceding and following information that gives extra meaning. The term "context" is used in ECMAScript to refer to [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), which is all the parameters, scope, and *this* within the scope of some executing code.

This is shown in [ECMA-262 section 10.4.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2):

> Set the ThisBinding to the same value as the ThisBinding of the
> calling execution context

Which clearly indicates that *this* is part of an execution context.

An execution context provides the surrounding information that adds meaning to the code that is being executed. It includes much more information than just the [*thisBinding*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.1).

The value of *this* isn't "context". It's just one part of an execution context. It's essentially a local variable that can be set by the call to any object and in strict mode, to any value at all.

Comment: Can't agree with this answer. The existence of the term "execution context" does not outlaw other uses of "context" any more than it outlaws other uses of "execution". Maybe there is a better term to describe `this` but none is offered here, and it's arguably too late to shut the door on "context".

Comment: @Roamer-1888—thank you for the edit. You're right, but my argument doesn't rely on the existence of "execution context" precluding the of "context" for some other purpose. Rather, it's based on "context" being inappropriate from both a technical and semantic perspective. I also think the use of "context" instead of "this" is dying out. I don't see any reason to find an alternative term to *this* or *thisBinding*, it just obfuscates and means at some point you have to explain that "context" is actually *this*, and that it isn't in anyway "context". :-)

Comment: I don't think you can say that *this* isn't in any way "context", when you have already admittted that it's one part of an execution context, where "execution" is merely adjectival.

Comment: @Roamer-1888—I'm not going to continue this conversation past this point. Yes, *this* is **part** of an execution context. Saying it's **the** context is like saying one player of a team is the team.

Answer (score 30):

First, you need to have a clear understanding of **`scope`** and behaviour of the **`this`** keyword in the context of **`scope`**.

**`this` & `scope`:**

---

There are two types of scope in JavaScript. They are:

1. Global Scope
2. Function Scope

In short, global scope refers to the window object. Variables declared in a global scope are accessible from anywhere.

On the other hand, function scope resides inside of a function. A variable declared inside a function cannot be accessed from the outside world normally.

The **`this`** keyword in the global scope refers to the window object. **`this`** inside a function also refers to the window object. So **`this`** will always refer to the window until we find a way to manipulate **`this`** to indicate a context of our own choosing.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-                                                                              -
-   Global Scope                                                               -
-   (globally "this" refers to window object)                                  -
-                                                                              -
-   function outer_function(callback){                                         -
-                                                                              -
-       // Outer function scope                                                -
-       // Inside the outer function, the "this" keyword                       -
-       //  refers to window object                                            -
-       callback() // "this" inside callback also refers to the  window object -
-   }                                                                          -
-                                                                              -
-   function callback_function(){                                              -
-                                                                              -
-       // Function to be passed as callback                                   -
-                                                                              -
-       // Here "THIS" refers to the window object also                        -
-   }                                                                          -
-                                                                              -
-   outer_function(callback_function)                                          -
-   // Invoke with callback                                                    -
-                                                                              -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Different ways to manipulate `this` inside callback functions:**

Here I have a constructor function called Person. It has a property called **`name`** and four method called **`sayNameVersion1`**, **`sayNameVersion2`**, **`sayNameVersion3`**, and **`sayNameVersion4`**. All four of them has one specific task. Accept a callback and invoke it. The callback has a specific task which is to log the name property of an instance of Person constructor function.

```
function Person(name){

    this.name = name

    this.sayNameVersion1 = function(callback){
        callback.bind(this)()
    }
    this.sayNameVersion2 = function(callback){
        callback()
    }

    this.sayNameVersion3 = function(callback){
        callback.call(this)
    }

    this.sayNameVersion4 = function(callback){
        callback.apply(this)
    }

}

function niceCallback(){

    // Function to be used as callback

    var parentObject = this

    console.log(parentObject)
}
```

Now let's create an instance from person constructor and invoke different versions of **`sayNameVersionX`** (X refers to 1,2,3,4) method with **`niceCallback`** to see how many ways we can manipulate the **`this`** inside callback to refer to the **`person`** instance.

```
var p1 = new Person('zami') // Create an instance of Person constructor
```

[**bind:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

What bind do is to create a new function with the **`this`** keyword set to the provided value.

`sayNameVersion1` and `sayNameVersion2` use bind to manipulate **`this`** of the callback function.

```
this.sayNameVersion1 = function(callback){
    callback.bind(this)()
}
this.sayNameVersion2 = function(callback){
    callback()
}
```

The first one binds **`this`** with a callback inside the method itself. And for the second one, the callback is passed with the object bound to it.

```
p1.sayNameVersion1(niceCallback) // pass simply the callback and bind happens inside the sayNameVersion1 method

p1.sayNameVersion2(niceCallback.bind(p1)) // uses bind before passing callback
```

---

[**call:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

The **`first argument`** of the **`call`** method is used as **`this`** inside the function that is invoked with **`call`** attached to it.

`sayNameVersion3` uses **`call`** to manipulate the **`this`** to refer to the person object that we created, instead of the window object.

```
this.sayNameVersion3 = function(callback){
    callback.call(this)
}
```

And it is called like the following:

```
p1.sayNameVersion3(niceCallback)
```

---

[**apply:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Similar to **`call`**, the first argument of **`apply`** refers to the object that will be indicated by the **`this`** keyword.

`sayNameVersion4` uses **`apply`** to manipulate **`this`** to refer to a person object

```
this.sayNameVersion4 = function(callback){
    callback.apply(this)
}
```

And it is called like the following. Simply the callback is passed,

```
p1.sayNameVersion4(niceCallback)
```

Comment: any constructive criticism regarding  the answer will be appreciated !

Comment: The this keyword in the global scope doesn't necessarily refer to the **window** object. That is true only in a browser.

Comment: @RandallFlagg i wrote this answer from a browser's perspective.Fell free to inhance this answer if necessary :)

Answer (score 24):

We can not bind this to `setTimeout()`, as it always executes with **the global object (Window)**. If you want to access the `this` context in the callback function then by using `bind()` to the callback function, we can achieve it as:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    this.methodName();
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

Comment: Re "`Window`": Isn't it "`window`" (lowercase)?

Answer (score 14):

The question revolves around how the `this` keyword behaves in JavaScript. `this` behaves differently as below,

1. The value of `this` is usually determined by a function execution context.
2. In the global scope, `this` refers to the global object (the `window` object).
3. If strict mode is enabled for any function then the value of `this` will be `undefined` as in strict mode, global object refers to `undefined` in place of the `window` object.
4. The object that is standing before the dot is what the `this` keyword will be bound to.
5. We can set the value of this explicitly with `call()`, `bind()`, and `apply()`
6. When the `new` keyword is used (a constructor), this is bound to the new object being created.
7. Arrow functions don’t bind `this` — instead, `this` is bound lexically (i.e., based on the original context)

As most of the answers suggest, we can use **the arrow function or `bind()` Method or Self** var. I would quote a point about lambdas (arrow function) from [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-functions-arrow-functions)

> Prefer using arrow functions over f.bind(this), and especially over
> goog.bind(f, this). Avoid writing const self = this. Arrow functions
> are particularly useful for callbacks, which sometimes pass unexpectedly
> additional arguments.

**Google clearly recommends using lambdas rather than bind or `const self = this`**

So the best solution would be to use lambdas as below,

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
  this.data = data;
  transport.on('data', () => {
    alert(this.data);
  });
}
```

References:

1. https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/javascript-this-4-rules-7354abdb274c
2. [arrow-functions-vs-bind](http://2ality.com/2016/02/arrow-functions-vs-bind.html)

Comment: This question is specifically about using functions/methods as callbacks. Your answer might be a better fit for https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196 .

Comment: I find your fourth point worded ambiguously. Consider the [example “Problem When Using Methods With The this Object as Callbacks”](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), where the right object is standing before the dot, but still the context is not that object.

Answer (score 9):

Currently there is another approach possible if classes are used in code.

With support of [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), it's possible to make it the following way:

```
class someView {
    onSomeInputKeyUp = (event) => {
        console.log(this); // This refers to the correct value
    // ....
    someInitMethod() {
        //...
        someInput.addEventListener('input', this.onSomeInputKeyUp)
```

For sure under the hood it's all the old good arrow function that binds context, but in this form it looks much more clear that explicit binding.

Since it's a Stage 3 Proposal, you will need [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) and appropriate [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to process it as for now (08/2018).

Comment: This is exactly the way I got it working in Typescript: ``public methodName = (params) => { body }`` inside a class.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach, which is **the standard way since DOM2** to bind `this` within the event listener, that **let you always remove the listener** (among other benefits), is the `handleEvent(evt)` method from the `EventListener` interface:

```
var obj = {
  handleEvent(e) {
    // always true
    console.log(this === obj);
  }
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', obj);
```

Detailed information about using `handleEvent` can be found here: *[DOM handleEvent: a cross-platform standard since year 2000](https://medium.com/@WebReflection/dom-handleevent-a-cross-platform-standard-since-year-2000-5bf17287fd38)*

Comment: I like this a lot. first place I've seen this. thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

### `this` in JavaScript:

The value of `this` in JavaScript is 100% determined by how a function is called, and not how it is defined. We can relatively easily find the value of `this` by the **'left of the dot rule'**:

1. When the function is created using the function keyword the value of `this` is the object left of the dot of the function which is called
2. If there is no object left of the dot then the value of `this` inside a function is often the global object (`global` in Node.js and `window` in a browser). I wouldn't recommend using the `this` keyword here because it is less explicit than using something like `window`!
3. There exist certain constructs like arrow functions and functions created using the `Function.prototype.bind()` a function that can fix the value of `this`. These are exceptions of the rule, but they are really helpful to fix the value of `this`.

### Example in Node.js

```
module.exports.data = 'module data';
// This outside a function in node refers to module.exports object
console.log(this);

const obj1 = {
    data: "obj1 data",
    met1: function () {
        console.log(this.data);
    },
    met2: () => {
        console.log(this.data);
    },
};

const obj2 = {
    data: "obj2 data",
    test1: function () {
        console.log(this.data);
    },
    test2: function () {
        console.log(this.data);
    }.bind(obj1),
    test3: obj1.met1,
    test4: obj1.met2,
};

obj2.test1();
obj2.test2();
obj2.test3();
obj2.test4();
obj1.met1.call(obj2);
```

Output:

[image]

Let me walk you through the outputs one by one (ignoring the first log starting from the second):

1. `this` is `obj2` because of the left of the dot rule, we can see how `test1` is called `obj2.test1();`. `obj2` is left of the dot and thus the `this` value.
2. Even though `obj2` is left of the dot, `test2` is bound to `obj1` via the `bind()` method. The `this` value is `obj1`.
3. `obj2` is left of the dot from the function which is called: `obj2.test3()`. Therefore `obj2` will be the value of `this`.
4. In this case: `obj2.test4()` `obj2` is left of the dot. However, arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding. Therefore it will bind to the `this` value of the outer scope which is the `module.exports` an object which was logged in the beginning.
5. We can also specify the value of `this` by using the `call` function. Here we can pass in the desired `this` value as an argument, which is `obj2` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing a problem with `Ngx` line chart `xAxisTickFormatting` function which was called from HTML like this: `[xAxisTickFormatting]="xFormat"`.

I was unable to access my component's variable from the function declared. This solution helped me to resolve the issue to find the correct this.

Instead of using the function like this:

```
xFormat (value): string {
  return value.toString() + this.oneComponentVariable; //gives wrong result
}
```

Use this:

```
 xFormat = (value) => {
   // console.log(this);
   // now you have access to your component variables
   return value + this.oneComponentVariable
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Some other people have touched on how to use the .bind() method, but specifically here is how you can use it with .then() if anyone is having trouble getting them to work together:

```
someFunction()
.then(function(response) {
    //'this' wasn't accessible here before but now it is
}.bind(this))
```

As mentioned in the comments, an alternative would be to use an arrow function that doesn't have its own 'this' value

```
someFunction()
.then((response)=>{
    //'this' was always accessible here
})
```

Comment: That's not correct. (1) arrow functions don't have their own `this` value and use the value from the closes `this`-providing environment. (2) because of that, `.bind` doesn't have an affect on arrow functions.

Comment: good call, I copied the code wrong, updated to show both variations

Answer (score 3):

You can use **arrow** function to avoid the issue with this .

```
const functionToTest = (dataToSet , transport) => {
  this.dataToSet = dataToSet ;
  transport.on('dataToSet ', () => {
    console.log(this.dataToSet);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved the problem

```js
class myClass
{
    constructor(parent)
    {
        this.callback = (function() { 
            this.callbackFunctionOfParent();             
        }).bind(parent);
    }

    callCallback() {
         this.callback();
    }
}

class Class2
{
       constructor()
       {
            this.Name = "CLASS 2";

            this.test = new myClass(this);

            this.test.callCallback();
       } 

       callbackFunctionOfParent()
       {
           console.log("parent is: " + this.Name);
       }
}

var c2 = new Class2;
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. At the very least you could write `this.callback = function() { parent.callbackFunctionOfParent() }` but I'm sure this could be simplified a lot more depending on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: The question was about accessing 'this' in the context of the derived class, not what is the simplest way to call a function on the parent class.

Comment: But why would you present a solution that is more difficult to understand? Solutions should be reduced to the absolute minimum so that they are easy to understand. According to your argument I could provide the following solution to the question "how to add two numbers" and it would be ok? `function mul(x, y) { return x * y; } function add(x, y) { return mul(x, 1) + mul(y, 1); }; add(41, 1)`

Comment: I think you are free to edit the post and make it more terse, if it is still understandable and gives the same result on "run code snippet", then I have no problem with this.